# working on headless browser. Its screenshot function does not work

Tags: c++, browser, chromium, headless

I am using headless browser from c++ code.
My requirement  is to take page screenshot.
Following is the code called from OnPageReady():

```
devtools_client_->GetEmulation()->GetExperimental()->SetVisibleSize(headless::emulation::SetVisibleSizeParams::Builder()
                    .SetHeight(900)
                    .SetWidth(900)
                    .Build());

devtools_client_->GetEmulation()->SetDeviceMetricsOverride(900,
                        900,
                        1,
                        false);

devtools_client_->GetEmulation()->GetExperimental()->SetPageScaleFactor(headless::emulation::SetPageScaleFactorParams::Builder()
                        .SetPageScaleFactor(1).Build());

devtools_client_->GetPage()->GetExperimental()->CaptureScreenshot(
                        headless::page::CaptureScreenshotParams::Builder()
                        .SetClip(headless::page::Viewport::Builder()
                            .SetX(0)
                            .SetY(0)
                            .SetScale(1)
                            .SetHeight(900)
                            .SetWidth(900)
                            .Build())
                        .SetFormat(headless::page::CaptureScreenshotFormat::PNG)
                        .SetFromSurface(true)
                        .Build(),
                        base::Bind(&HeadlessExample::OnScreenshotCaptured,
                            weak_factory_.GetWeakPtr()));
```

But my issue is that OnScreenshotCaptured function does not get called.
Please help.

Ankur Sehgal.